# Response bot using keywords

Tags: php, while-loop, switch-statement, stringtokenizer

I made a q&a bot using PHP codes. It works in a way where the user has to key in questions in the 'Search' bar provided. After clicking on the 'Submit' button, the program will search for specific keywords and reply to the question asked. However, how do I show just one reply if there are more than one keywords in the question asked? Also, how do I display an error message when the user does not ask a question without the specific keywords?

```
if (isset($_GET['searchterm']))
{
$question = $_GET['searchterm'];
echo "<b>$question</b>";
echo "<br />";

$token = strtok($question, " ");

while($token !== false)
{
$token = strtok(" ");

switch ($token) {
case "hot":
    print "It is now ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"." hot"."<br>";
    break;
case "cold":
    print "It is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"."<br>";
    break;
 case "warm":
    print "It is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"." warm"."<br>";
    break;
case "cool":
    print "The temperature is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"." cool"."<br>";
    break;
case "temperature":
    print "The temperature now is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"."<br>";
    break;
case "current":
    print "The current temperature is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"."<br>";
    break;
case "weather":
    print "We are now having ".$data['weather'][0]['main']."<br>";
    break;  
case "wind":
    print "The wind speed is currently ".$data['wind']['speed']. " m/s"."<br>";
    break;      
}
}   
}
else {
    print "Sorry, we did not understand your question.";
}
```

Comment: You could exit your `while` loop as soon as you have provided 1 answer by adding an extra condition on a specific variable (e.g. : `$exit == true`) that you would have initialized to `false` before the loop and set this value to true in each `case` statement right after the print. That also would come handy regarding your second question : after leaving the loop, if this variable is `true` , you know you answered the question, if it is still `false`, you know you weren't able to understand it and can display an appropriate message.

Comment: strtok () ?? php or C++ ?

Comment: @CodingAnt I am using PHP codes.

Comment: @Bartdude Could you please provide the codes? It would help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Certainly not, that is not the goal of SO. You should try by yourself, this is really not a big deal and can really be summarized with the simple steps I described.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use default conditon on your code:
switch ($i) {
    switch ($token) 
        {
            case "hot":
                print "It is now ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"." hot"."<br>";
                break;
            case "cold":
                print "It is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"."<br>";
                break;
             case "warm":
                print "It is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"." warm"."<br>";
                break;
            case "cool":
                print "The temperature is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"." cool"."<br>";
                break;
            case "temperature":
                print "The temperature now is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"."<br>";
                break;
            case "current":
                print "The current temperature is ".$data['main']['temp']. " °C"."<br>";
                break;
            case "weather":
                print "We are now having ".$data['weather'][0]['main']."<br>";
                break;  
            case "wind":
                print "The wind speed is currently ".$data['wind']['speed']. " m/s"."<br>";
                break;
            default:
            print "wrong question";
        }
}
```

Comment: @GThamizh I tried using your codes but everytime a question is asked and printed out, the "wrong question" is also printed out.